# Importing data from XML file to strings

Tags: c#, xml, string

I have been searching for an answer for 24 hours, but I did not find it. I am new to C#. I have found a tutorial, from where I have used this code:

```
XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("PeopleCustom.xml");
var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("Person")
                           where c.Attribute("Age").Value == current.ToString()
                           select new Person
                           {
                               FirstName = (string)c.Attribute("FirstName").Value,
                           };

listBox1.ItemsSource = filteredData;
public class Person
    {
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
        int age;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstname; }
            set { firstname = value; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastname; }
            set { lastname = value; }
        }


        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }


    }
```

XML is like this:

```
<People>
<Person
   FirstName="Kate"
   LastName="Smith"
   Age="1" />
<Person 
       ...
               />
</People>
```

It works, but it puts all output into listbox. I want strings. I tried to get string from list box (like this listBox1.Items[0].ToString();), but all I get is something like this: ProjectName.MainPage+Person. I also tried to get it from filteredData, but no success.
Is there any way to get data from XML to strings? Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code

```
XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("PeopleCustom.xml");
var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("Person")
                           where c.Attribute("Age").Value == current.ToString()
                           select new Person
                           {
                               FirstName = (string)c.Attribute("FirstName").Value,
                           };
```

makes a list of Person objects: `select New Person{.....}`

If you want a list of string of the `Person`'s first name, then all you have to do is change what object the LINQ is creating....

```
select (string)c.Attribute("FirstName").Value );
```

now, it makes a new string from the `FirstName` attribute.

after this linq is run, you will basically have a linq object that will produce a list of strings.  if you want a List then modify like this:

```
XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("PeopleCustom.xml");
var filteredData =( from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("Person")
                           where c.Attribute("Age").Value == current.ToString()
                           select (string)c.Attribute("FirstName").Value ).ToList();
```

if you want the first string in the list...

```
filterdData.First();
```

Comment: Sorry, I cant vote up your answer, I do not have enough rep. Thanks again

Comment: Is there any way to convert filteredData directly to string, without using listbox? filteredData.ToString(); is not working

Answer (score 0):

From the output you are getting listBox1.items contains person objects so you could try

```
var name = ((Person)listBox1.Items[0]).FirstName;
```

this should give you the value

Comment: Sorry, this did not work. It says that there is no definition for Firstname.